# Как в Kivy>TextInput сделать невыделяемый текст?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
TextInput:
            text: 'электродвижущая сила (a)'
            id: second
            input_type: 'number'
            input_filter: 'float'
            multiline: False
```

(как тут [image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать параметр `hint_text`:

```
TextInput:
    ...
    hint_text: 'Some text'
```